# timespamp convert php

Tags: php, timestamp

How do I convert the standard php timestamp e.g. 1278184362 into this format 
2010-07-03 19:00:00 ?

needs to be exact...

Any ideas guys?

Comment: PHP has an excellent [Manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you might want to have a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$timestamp = 1278184362;

$newDate = Date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```